# Ping bot response time command not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command, bots

Why is this command not working I am new to coding and would really appreciate some help I am simply trying to get a bot response time ping command to work this is not producing any errors anymore but it doesn't work either and as I am not getting any errors I am having difficulty discovering the problem on my own.

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot)
      return;
  
    let command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(1);
    let args = message.content.replace('.' + command, '').trim();
  
    switch (command) {
      case 'ping': {
        message.channel.send('Pong! (~ ' + client.ping + 'ms)');
        break;
      }
  
  
      case 'uptime': {
        // client.uptime is in millseconds
        // this is just maths, I won't explain much of it
        // % is modulo, AKA the remainder of a division
        let days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
        let hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
        let minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
        let seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;
  
        message.channel.send(`__Uptime:__\n${days}d ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`);
        break;
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're checking if [`GuildChannel#type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type) is `text`, which is not a valid [`ChannelType`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType).

Instead, try using `GUILD_TEXT`.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT' || message.author.bot)
        return;

    let command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(1);
    let args = message.content.replace('.' + command, '').trim();

    switch (command) {
        case 'ping': {
            message.channel.send('Pong! (~ ' + client.ping + 'ms)');
            break;
        }


        case 'uptime': {
            // client.uptime is in millseconds
            // this is just maths, I won't explain much of it
            // % is modulo, AKA the remainder of a division
            let days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
            let hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
            let minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
            let seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;

            message.channel.send(`__Uptime:__\n${days}d ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Note**: In April of 2022 access to message content will become a Privileged Intent. I really recommend you to switch to [`Slash Commands`](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html).

Read more here: [`Message Content: Privileged Intent for Verified Bots`](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055)

Comment: Thank you for getting helping that did get the bot responding but it responds with undefined ms instead of the actual milliseconds so the command still isn't exactly working do you have any idea why this might be the case.

Comment: @ManicCoder Have you tried logging `client.uptime`? Is it undefined?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. Just to clarify you mean console log the event or interaction or whatever you'd call it yeh? do you know of a guide that can show me the info I need to learn how to do this I am extremely new to all this but ready and eager to learn

Comment: Try running `console.log(client.uptime)` inside the `messageCreate` event to see whether it is undefined or not.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it properly and it's console logging numbers which I assume means it's not undefined in the terminal but it's still undefined in the message on discord.

Comment: @ManicCoder We shall move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240575/discussion-between-jakye-and-maniccoder).